# Why does כרת וערירי (Excision and Childlessness) come after "death at the hand of Heaven"?

Tags: tefilla, prayer-book

While davening from the Machzor, I noticed this seemingly strange anomaly. At the end in the text of the Al Chet prayer it says, "וְעַל חֲטָאִים שֶׁאָֽנוּ חַיָּבִים עֲלֵיהֶם כָּרֵת וַעֲרִירִי - *And for sins for which we incur the penalty of excision and childlessness."*

It seems that כרת וערירי is out of order. If these are in order of severity, it would seem that this should come before "מִיתָה בִּידֵי שָׁמָֽיִם - *the penalty of death by the hand of Heaven"*

In addition, כרת (being cut off) and ערירי (childlessness) are two distinct punishments. Why are they grouped together?

Comment: Both of them extend past death.

Comment: Some girsaot list just כרת (my machazor says כרת then notes in parentheses that י"א וערירי)

Comment: Can you explain why exactly they are worse? Do you mean in terms of the sins that lead to them or the severity of the punishment?

Answer (score 2):

Tosafos (eishesh achiv meimo) in yevamos 2a
Would answer all of your questions.
First, kares is more severe than misa bidei shamayim because the death is earlier ( acc to yerushalmi before 50, and babli before 60, and bidei shamayim is at 60 and little).
According to rashi, ariri and kares are the same thing, if you get kares you get ariri.
According to the riva, it's possible to split them, however it seems if a person gets ariri he also gets kares, so it would make sense to put it together, because ariri is a catagory of kares, it's not worse then like we have the 4 deaths together.